# Azure function C# blob output binding filename

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

In a standard example the name for output trigger filename is set from input.
For example "name"

```
[Function("BlobFunction")]
[BlobOutput("test-samples-output/{name}-output.txt", Connection = "BlobConnectionString")]
public void Run(
   [BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "BlobConnectionString")] string myBlob, 
   string name
   )
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {myBlob}");
}
```

Other possibility is {rand-guid} or something with Datetime.

But I would like to set the output filename without having an input var "name". With a variable name I can chose and a value I can set as I want.
For example in a timer triggered function. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and can able to set a name that I want to save as a blob.

**Code:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.IO;

public static class TimerFunction
{
    [FunctionName("TimerFunction")]
    public static void Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
        [Blob("<container-name>/{fileName}.txt", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "BlobConneString")] out string blobContent,
        ILogger log)
    {
        string customFileName = "<{fileName}.txt>"; 
        blobContent = $"The content of the blob with filename is: {customFileName}";

        log.LogInformation($"Blob {customFileName} is created successfully.");
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "BlobConneString": "<storage-account-conne-string>"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

Then, the blob was saved to my storage account container in Azure Portal as below,

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But you are not using output binding. Implementing the client is of course an option. Using output binding is much easier and afaik "the way" to do it.

Comment: @waltavista I updated my answer with an output binding.

Comment: Mhm, it is working because you use
"<container-name>/{DateTime}-{rand-guid}.txt"
and
string fileName = $"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}-{Guid.NewGuid()}.txt";

Try to use fileName as variable in 
"<container-name>/{fileName}.txt"

That is what I was talking about.